Not able to point my Application Gateway to my Azure Container apps
I am currently migrating my GCP workload to Azure and I need some help in understanding some design choices in Azure.
My current GCP setup is very simple. We have a Global external load balancer with a public IP for the frontend, which points to an instance group(VMs) and 8 other backend services as backend, hosted on cloud run. I'm facing some issues in replicating the same on Azure.
I understand that I need an application gateway(or a front door?)as a load balancer and add backend pools to it. But I'm not sure how to achieve this in case of my microservices. I'm confused between using either Container Instance or Container Apps.I need the capability to scale up and down my dockerized containers automatically, just like in cloud run. I've gone through some links that pointed to using Container Apps. But I can't find a way to link a Container App as a backend pool in my Application gateway. I already have my domains, so I need custom domain for each entity(one instance and 8 microservices) in the backend pool along with Managed certificates for SSL. I also need URL based routing for each of my microservice (Container app).
It would be of great help if someone can point me to the right direction in replicating my GCP workload in a similar way on Azure.

To set up your services in Azure, you can follow these steps using the Azure portal:
Create an Azure Container App for each of your microservices.
Create an Application Gateway and add backend pools that target your Container Apps.
Configure URL-based routing for each of your microservices using path-based rules.
Associate custom domains and SSL certificates with your Application Gateway and App Service instances.

You dont need an app gateway with container app. it has a public iup and load balancer by default


I understand that I need an application gateway (or a front door?) as a load balancer and add backend pools to it.

Ans- Yes, you need to set up Azure Application Gateway

But I'm not sure how to achieve this

Ans-

Navigate to Application Gateways > Add.
Choose the same region as your Container Apps.
Create a new virtual network or select an existing one that can access the Container Apps.
Configure a public IP address.
Set up the HTTP settings and listeners based on your application's needs.
Add a routing rule for each service.
Choose a SKU that supports autoscaling if needed.




I'm confused between using either Container Instance or Container Apps

Ans- Given your specific requirements, including the need for auto-scaling, URL-based routing, SSL management, and custom domain support for your microservices, Azure Container Apps is the more suitable option


I need the capability to scale up and down

Ans- Container Apps has scaling option where you can scale up or down your environment as per your need.


I can't find a way to link a Container App as a backend pool in my application gateway

Ans-
To link your container app with the backend pool, under your application gateway backend pool add your container app url's IP address (you will get the IP address by resolving the url using nslookup  ) Once you get the IP address, paste it in your target for backend pool as below.  Update your DNS settings at your domain registrar to point to the public IP address of the Application Gateway. Done.

References:

Protect Azure Container Apps with Web Application Firewall on Application Gateway
Configure App Service with Application Gateway
Using load-balancing services in Azure
Application Gateway integration


you dont "need" an app gateway with container app.
